# Syntax Error In Ruby Script Appears In CMD

Tags: ruby

I don't know why whenever I run this code in CMD ,I got this error:

> Syntax error, unexpected =>

Here's my code:

```
   hash_brown = (
    "topping_1" => "Sour Cream",
    "topping_2" => "Butter",
    "topping_3" => "Salt",
    "topping_4" => "Ketchup"
)

puts hash_brown["topping_2"]

first_hash = Hash.new

first_hash["first_name"] = "Jacob"
first_hash["nick_name"] = "Day"
first_hash["last_name"] = "Williams"

puts first_hash["first_hash"]

$end
```

Please let me know what is wrong with it cause I have checked it thousands of times & didn't found anything!

Comment: In Ruby, literal hashes are bound by `{}` curly braces, not `()` parens as you have them.  `hash_brown = { ... }`

Comment: What is it you think that `$end` is doing? There is no reason for it to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use curly braces (`{}`) to define Hash objects:

```
hash_brown = {
    "topping_1" => "Sour Cream",
    "topping_2" => "Butter",
    "topping_3" => "Salt",
    "topping_4" => "Ketchup"
}
```